# Change name of GPT Partition (not label) under Windows from command line

Tags: windows, partition, fdisk, gpt

I need to change the **name** of a GPT partition (not a filesystem label), and I haven't found any way to do it under Windows, except for [this tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/).

The problem is that it's interactive and doesn't support being called from the command line, so no scripting is possible.

How else can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by GPT "Name"? The UID of the volume?

Comment: @bjoster Yes. In Gparted it shows "name".

Answer (score 1):

A partition **name** is a name given in the GPT; it's external to the partition itself. It is set when the GPT is created (automatically under Windows). A partition label is a string stored inside the filesystem; for example with ext-family filesystems, NTFS or FAT; this is the label you can manipulate with label/e2label etc.

The is no (supported) way to manipulated the GPT **name** under windows (directly). Under Linux it's done with

```
tune2fs -L vmguest_root /dev/sda1
```

tune2fs for Windows does *not support* changing the GPT name; it just supports chaning the feature bits of ext partitions.

Windows supports changing the label, not the name. Normally, the name of created GPT partitions should match the volume GUID.

Comment: So, there's no tool able to do (under Windows) that can be scripted? :(

Comment: No official supported ones, no. As far as I know there is a Win32 port of gdisk, but I don't know how good it is. Sorry.